# Detached HEAD Issue in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, github, head

I am new to Android Studio and have began developing a Navigation Drawer app.

After having made a mistake in a commit, I played around with the Version control's "Checkout Revision" and now I can no longer push my project onto Github due to a "Detached HEAD".

How can I fix this problem? My app runs perfectly fine in the emulator.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

you can go to VCS menu then Git, Branches, then in Git Branches dialog click on item below local branches then checkout branches and then accept your default branches.
it will connect your project to it's default branch and you can commit your project.

Answer (score 8):

If you already made a lot of changes and want to commit and push online but out of sudden got this detached head issue, here are steps you can do for Git through Android Studio:

1. Go to VCS -> Git -> Branches...
2. Click the +New Branch, just put any temporary name.
3. Then commit your changes to the new branch (don't push yet, since it'll create new branch online).
4. Go to VCS -> Git -> Branches... again and now select the previous branch(local) with the detached head issue and click checkout branch.
5. Go to VCS -> Git -> Branches... again and now select the newly created branch(local) and select merge into current.
6. After success merge, double check if your code is the latest one. Now you can push the branch(previously got issue) without detached head issue. If you click commit at this point there'll be nothing to be committed since you have merged the latest changes. All you need to do is just push online. By this you prevent yourself from creating new branch online just to fix this issue.
7. For cleaning purpose, once you managed to push the branch online, just select again the newly created branch(local) and click delete branch.

Answer (score 0):

When you are in a 'detached head state' in Git, it means you are currently viewing history according to a past commit that is not on a branch. A few things need to happen based on what your goal is.

If you want to continue your code in the currently checked out version? If so, you should check back out to the most recently made commit and then un-do history with `git revert` or `git reset`, whichever makes more sense for you.

If you want to just go back to your most recent commit and continue to work as normal, `git checkout <newest SHA>` will work totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid from Detached Head you need to know why this problem is arrived. Its Showing Detached Head because you merge your project several times(or atlas twice) by just committing your project locally. **What you need to do is that by every time you merge your project just commit it locally as well as to server branch too**.
This will resolve your problem as it does mine.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest quick solution is just to create new branch and push your current version there.
However, this solution is not the right one.

Answer (score 0):

I created a branch and copy a commit to this one with command

```
git cherry-pick <commit number>
```